# Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources' (Buildozer Kivy)

Tags: android, python, kivy, apk, buildozer

I created a Kivy application and Buildozer generated this error when compiling it (Error log from terminal):

```
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'. 
Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details. 

Try:    
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

I've established all the necessary dependencies indicated on Kivy's website.
I tried to run the apk build with the options that the log recommended, but nothing has changed.

Can this error occur because I use a .kv file markup to create an interface window? 
Has anyone ever encountered one of these before? How can I fix this?

I'm using linux Xubuntu 18.04, Buildozer version is latest, Cython version - 0.25.2

My Buildozer.spec

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = TicTacToe

# (str) Package name
package.name = TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.test

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.10.0

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 17c

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activites = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#
```

And buildozer log:

```
 running gradlew assembleDebug
[DEBUG]:    /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:6: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'org.test.tictactoe_mobile_v0.1'.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * What went wrong:
[DEBUG]:    Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
[DEBUG]:    > Failed to process resources, see aapt output above for details.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Try:
[DEBUG]:    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD FAILED in 1s
[DEBUG]:    13 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 11 up-to-date
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    
Exception in thread background thread for pid 14047:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.6.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1/gradlew assembleDebug

  STDOUT:
/home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:6: AAPT: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'org.test.tictactoe_mobile_v0.1'.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

BUILD FAILED in 1s  
13 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 11 up-to-date  

[INFO]:    STDERR:

[INFO]:    COMMAND:
cd /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1 && /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1/gradlew assembleDebug

[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1/gradlew failed!
WARNING: Received a --sdk argument, but this argument is deprecated and does nothing.
No compiled python is present to zip, skipping.
No setup.py/pyproject.toml used, copying full private data into .apk.
Applying Java source code patches...
Applying patch: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied: src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain apk --debug --bootstrap=sdl2 --dist_name TicTacToe_mobile_v0.1 --name TicTacToe --version 0.1 --package org.test.tictactoe_mobile_v0.1 --android_api 27 --minsdk 21 --ndk-api 21 --private /home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/app --orientation portrait --window --copy-libs --arch armeabi-v7a --color=always --storage-dir="/home/unchpokable/Kivy/TicTacToe/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
```

Comment: Using main.py with kv file in Buildozer is fine. Could you please provide your `buildozer.spec` and also the buildozer log. What is your Java version?

Comment: To tell the truth, I don't know what version of Java I have, or if I have it at all.  It's the first time I've heard that you need to install Java to compile Python Kivy applications.

Comment: Try removing `v0.1` in `package.name`, e.g. `package.name = TicTacToe_mobile`. Open a terminal window and execute `java -version`. "If you target Android, you must install at least Cython, few build libs, and a Java SDK."

Comment: Thanks, dude. The problem was just the name of the package being created. I took it out of the v0.1 name and it all worked out at once)

Comment: I had a similar issue, where the package.name needed to have all dashes removed.